# Why does Stack Overflow allow to downvote an accepted answer when you are the asker?

Tags: discussion

Why does Stack Overflow allow to downvote an accepted answer when you are the asker?

What would be a good use-case where both accepting the answer and downvoting it would be the right thing to do ?

Comment: If the answer is not valid anymore.

Comment: @UnderDog But then if you know the answer is not valid anymore, that means you know what is the valid answer meaning that you should instead simply post the new one and accept it.

Comment: It is up to OP to accept the answer or not, unless OP is the one posting the answer, and yes, you should do that too (posting correct answer), but you should also downvote an accepted answer if it is not correct/valid anymore.

Comment: @UnderDog You misunderstood my question, I mean in the case where you are the question asker.

Comment: Accepting is "this solved my problem". Voting is "this is not a useful answer (to others?)". A poorly written answer that solved my problem may get accepted, but its still poorly written and not a useful one to others reading it.

Comment: But then it would be better to edit it or post a correct version instead of downvoting it ?

Comment: Why block such an action? Adding complexity to disallow a rare (though valid) use case? Lets' flip the question - why disallow it?

Comment: You didnt frame the question right. So, you are saying that you asked the question, and you accepted an answer, and now you are downvoting that accepted answer, so, why SO allows that? Is that your question?

Comment: If I asked a question, someone answered, it solved my problem, but then I realized that it missed an edge case or it is not completely correct, I will unaccept it, downvote it, and comment on it. I guess all you are asking is, that the downvoting should only be valid/allowed after I unaccept it. Right?

Comment: This is a huge oversight and should be brought to the developers' attention immediately.

Answer (score 19):

<strike>Just because the person who asked the question thinks something is the right answer does not guarantee that it is indeed the best answer.</strike>

There are many cases on this site where an outright wrong or dangerous answer has been accepted. It should be perfectly fine to be able to downvote those.

In response to your new question: frankly, a user both accepting and downvoting an answer is such a rare occurrence that I don't think it's worth developer time covering that edge case. Why add specific conditional logic for something that is vanishingly rare?

I've seen users upvote something and flag it as "very low quality" at the same time. Why? Who knows, but it's not high on the list of priorities to block.

Comment: You're asking why the system allows it, and he's saying it's because the developers never considered disallowing it.

Answer (score 18):

> What would be a good use-case where both accepting the answer and downvoting it would be the right thing to do ?

When it answers your question, but it sucks.

Comment: Why are people upvoting this answer? It sucks.

Comment: Personally I'd like to accept it and then down-vote it.

Answer (score 3):

The only reasonable thing that I could think of seeing this kind of behavior is that the answer is right, but doesn't fit the problem at its best. **The OP may have downvoted the accepted answer in order to spur the answerer to improve it**.

This is by the way very uncommon, and I wouldn't personally accept an answer if I don't feel good with it. In this kind of situation, **I would rather comment and share my thoughts with the user who posted it, or just edit it by myself and then accept it**.

Comment: That's also what I would do. And I think this is the right thing to do in such a case which made me wonder why it is allowed. Upvoted.